# Обмен данными Unity3d(клиент) и Node.js(сервер)

Tags: c#, node.js, unity3d, post

Хочу наладить обмен информации сервер-клиент(Node.js<->Unity3D)
В случае с серверной частью беру такой скрипт.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url'); 
var querystring = require('querystring');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.');


function accept(req, res) {

console.log(req);
// через 1.5 секунды ответить сообщением
setTimeout(function() {
  res.end('текст ответа ' + new Date() + req.url);
}, 1500);

}

if (!module.parent) {
http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
} else {
exports.accept = accept;

}
console.log("Starting");
```

Данный скрипт работает вполне себе хорошо. При заходе с браузера на него (http://127.0.0.1:8080/) выдает большой обьем информации в console.log вида

```
 IncomingMessage {
_readableState:
 ReadableState {
 objectMode: false,
 highWaterMark: 16384,
 buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
 length: 0,
 pipes: null,
 pipesCount: 0,
 flowing: null,
 ended: false,
 endEmitted: false,
 reading: false,
 sync: true,
```

И так далее. Но когда я пытаюсь просто послать запрос с Unity 3D

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    { 
    Debug.Log("Закинули на сервер данные POST");
    POST();
    }
}

public IEnumerator POST()
{
    var Data = new WWWForm();
    Data.AddField("variable1", "Текст 1");
    var Query = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1:8080/server.js", Data);
    //Можно посылать и без данных, например так
    //WWW Query = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1:8080/server.js");
    //И всё равно не работает.
    yield return Query;
    if (Query.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server does not respond : " + Query.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Server responded : " + Query.text);
    }
    Query.Dispose();
}
```

То в ответ не приходит ничего. Более того, консоль на стороне сервера, столь бурно реагировавшая на заход с браузера, тоже ничего не пишет. Судя по всему, запрос просто не доходит до неё.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно оформлен код на стороне Unity:

```
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("variable1","Текст 1");

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://...", form);
        yield return www.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Eugene Bartosh посоветовал интересный способ, но ничего не заработало. 
В итоге выяснилось что проблема была в том куске кода, где я пытался вызвать

```
IEnumerator POST()
```

простым вызовом

```
private void Update()
{
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
{ 
Debug.Log("Закинули на сервер данные POST");
POST();
}
}
```

Разумеется, надо через

```
StartCoroutine(POST());
```

С таким кодом уже всё заработало, и в первом варианте и в варианте от Евгения.

Comment: Аааа, тогда канешна, там где WWW - только coroutine...